# Typo3 missing page type icons

Tags: typo3

For my new typo3 page I want to add several pages and links. Unfortunately on my fresh 4.5 (I tried 4.7 as well) installation the icons in the page module for the different page types ar missing.

[image]

How can I get this icons?

Comment: [My request](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/33887) to show them by default was [rejected for usability reasons](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/33901).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are 'hidden' under the icon with green plus (left top corner at your screenshot), click it first.